# Google Custom Search How to Index Directory and All Sub Directories?

Tags: seo

I have added a sitemap to google webmaster tool with a single entry of

```
http://mydomain/myforum.php
```

At www.google.com/cse i tried Index Now for both Specific URLs and URLs in a sitemap but still google won't traverse and index all links at myforum.php.

How do i get google to traverse and index all links at myforum.php?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but about website administration. It belongs on [webmasters.se].

Comment: Hmm should i ask this question again at webmasters section or is there a way to move this question?

Comment: Questions can sometimes be migrated, but it's usually a slow and uncertain process, you'd be better off asking again on [webmasters.se].